# Code signing error in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, settings, signing

I want to run my app on my device instead of on the simulator, but every time I try to run it, I get a code signing error:

- 'AppName' requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
- Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

I added a provisioning profile to the build settings under 'Code signing' but I still keep getting this error. Is there something wrong with my provisioning profile or am I looking in the wrong place? By the way, I used this provisioning profile on the previous version of Xcode and never ran into any problems.

Comment: Is it a paid or free developer account?

Comment: @Paulo Free developer account. Does that matter? I've always had a free developer account and I was still able to test apps on my device in the past (Xcode 7). On the Apple website, it says I should have limited testing capabilities with a free developer account.

Comment: Okay so, you should do something like yourappUITests folder. Set the bundle id to that instead.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? Same problem here.

Comment: @StijnSpijker Yeah, when you're on the settings page you have to make sure you have the <yourappname>.app file selected. You can find that in a pane on the left side of the settings page (not the Xcode window, but the actual settings page with white background). If that pane is hidden, you have to make it appear by clicking the pane icon in the left bottom corner. (By the way, I had the answer typed in my original post but it got deleted by the moderator Eric Aya (the one above your comment). Very nice to see he warned me about this...)

Answer (score 13):

To fix it, I set  > TARGETS  > General tab > Signing > Automatically manage signing = CHECK MARK

Comment: This should be the accept answer. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.abc.xyz" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and it was because my iPhone Developer certificate had expired. You can check this with the Keychain Access app in Utilities.

Comment: Checked it out, and it expires on September 20th, 2017 (one year from now). I created the iOS Developer certificate just yesterday, so that can't be the problem. I DO have the certificate, the only problem is that I can't code sign my app with that certificate.